# Intellij IDEA plugin development: Cannot get progress indicator for IntentionAction

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to display a progress bar when running a custom `IntentionAction` in my custom IntellIJ IDEA plugin.

However, it is not displayed no matter what I do. To test whether the problem lies in the `IntentionAction`, I copy-paste the code to a simple implementation of an `AnAction`. The whole class looks like so:

```
    public class HelloAction extends AnAction {
    public HelloAction() {
        super("Hello");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        Project project = event.getData(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT);
        ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Modal(project, "daf", false) {
            public void run(ProgressIndicator indicator) {
                indicator.setText("This is how you update the indicator");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                indicator.setFraction(0.5);  // halfway done
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });
        Messages.showMessageDialog(project, "Hello world!", "Greeting", Messages.getInformationIcon());
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. And when I use the same code inside an `IntentionAction`, nothing is displayed.

```
public class GenerateIntentionAction extends PsiElementBaseIntentionAction implements IntentionAction {
...
public void invoke(@NotNull Project project, Editor editor, @NotNull PsiElement element) throws IncorrectOperationException {
        ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Modal(project, "daf", false) {
            public void run(ProgressIndicator indicator) {
                indicator.setText("This is how you update the indicator");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                indicator.setFraction(0.5);  // halfway done
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });
```

I tried to run call `runWithProgressSynchronously` instead of `run`, tried making `Task` `Modal` and `Backgroundable` - to no avail. I do not know what is wrong besides the fact that `ProgressIndicator` inside `IntentionAction` is always an `EmptyProgressIndicator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention action is invoked inside `WriteAction`, you can't show modal UI from there. Overriding `startInWriteAction` and returning `false` might help.